# DC power supply directions tell me to short the leads

Tags: dc

I recently purchased a Longwei DC Power Supply Variable, 30 V 10 A, from Amazon, for small electrolysis projects. The directions tell me to plug in the unit, makes sure it is off. For constant current make certain the Volts are turned up to max and Amps to minimum, then short between the leads using a wire, and the lead clips.
After that, turn on the unit and set current where desired.

The translation the company used is less than precise.

What is not clear to me is am I supposed to turn the unit on while the leads are shorted?
The company has not answered my question.

I would like to know the purpose of this shorting, and whether is should be done with power on, or off.
So far, I'm on my third electrolysis project. I've done the shorting, but only with the unit power off. This makes little sense to me, unless it is to discharge some residual charge?
Your advice is appreciated.  :)

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to turn the unit on with the leads shorted to set the current to the desired limit. Then turn it off again. While off, connect the leads to your apparatus, then turn it back on.

Comment: Most power supplies that have a variable constant current output have the current-setting knob with a calibrated dial around it.

Answer (score 3):

Normally a bench power supply will limit output current to the set value. When this occurs, it acts like a current source. So it is both a current-limited voltage source and a voltage-limited current source, depending on how you use it.

Some power supplies simply display the current limit, which allows you to adjust it with the knob.

Others only display the instantaneous output current. In this case you have to put the supply into current limit mode (by shorting the output) then the current it will display will be its current limit value, and you can then adjust it.

If you have a fragile load like a LED, you should also adjust the voltage to a bit above the intended value. If the voltage is set to maximum, and you then connect the LED while the supply is powered, then the output capacitor will discharge into the LED, and the current limit may not react fast enough,  so the LED will get 30V for maybe a few tens of µs, long enough to blow it up. An electrolyzer should withstand overload much better.

Comment: The current limit ABSOLUTELY will not act fast enough on this type of supply. They have large output capacitors after the current limit circuit.

Comment: A test with a low value current sense resistor and a scope will tell the truth. Some psu's are much worse than others...

Answer (score 2):

They want you to preset the current low to limit the power on surge with minimal load.

A well-designed supply will protect itself under any preset on power-up.

It's just a matter of aging on components with startup currents.

Shorting is not needed for any other reason.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to set the current limit value.

If you only care about the current, then setting the V to max. helps ensure you can get that level of current. However if you are doing electrolysis and don't need such a high voltage, you can set the voltage lower. The output will never exceed the V setting or the I setting.

Be aware that if you do set the V high, and then short the leads, you will likely see a noticeable spark as the output capacitor in the supply discharges. This is not a problem, and is not dangerous. If you want to avoid it, just set the output V low (say 1 or 2 V) before shorting. If your wire resistance is low enough, you will still achieve the current limit value. To confirm, you can adjust the voltage *after* shorting -- the current shouldn't change.